# Newbie question: Need help with ContextTypeName

Tags: asp.net

I was following the Contoso University tutorial on the asp.net website and it all works well. My next step was to replicate some of the things on my own new website. I have added an EntityDataSource that works:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="ProductTypeEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=MyWebsite2011Entities" 
        DefaultContainerName="MyWebsite2011Entities" EnableFlattening="False" 
        EntitySetName="product_type">
```

And according to the tutorial it is a good idea to replace the ConnectionString and DefaultContainerName with a ContextTypeName.

"In the markup for the EntityDataSource control, remove the ConnectionString and DefaultContainerName attributes and replace them with a ContextTypeName="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolEntities" attribute. This is a change you should make every time you create an EntityDataSource control, unless you need to use a connection that is different from the one that's hard-coded in the object context class."

That worked fine for me in the tutorial where they had a:

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="StudentsEntityDataSource" runat="server"
        ContextTypeName="ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolEntities"
        EnableFlattening="False"
        EntitySetName="People"
        EnableDelete="True" EnableUpdate="True">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

The difference for me (besides the project name) is that my entity model is not placed in a DAL folder. Instead I accepted the Visual Web Developer's default folder name recommendation. I believe it was "App_Code". But the ContextTypeName="MyWebsite2011.App_Code.MyWebsite2011Entities" doesn't work. When I start the browser, it complains that the type MyWebsite2011.App_Code.MyWebsite2011Entities could not be read.

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="ProductTypeEntityDataSource" runat="server" 
        ContextTypeName="MyWebsite2011.App_Code.MyWebsite2011Entities"
        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="product_type">
```

How do I find the correct ContextTypeName to put in? As I said, the ConnectionString and DefaultContainerName worked, so I guess the MyWebsite2011Entities is ok. Any hints would be appreciated because I don't know the naming convention or what to look for.

Comment: ContextTypeName referred to your namespace.className instead file name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open up the .cs file in which the Context is declared, and look at text immediately after the `namespace` declaration. That's your class's namespace. Your ContextTypeName should be `<namespace>.<classname>` (without the <> brackets, of course.)

Comment: I found it in App_Code/MyWebsite2011.edmx/MyWebsite2011.Designer.cs. It turns out that the correct ContextTypeName was MyWebsite2011Model.MyWebsite2011Entities. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kasper No problem! Feel free to mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was following the same Contoso University tutorial but I was using windows Azure as an online Database.
So I also ran into this problem.
For other people interested on how to fix this when using an online database, I did the following.

With your EntityDataSource do:
Remove the following:

ConnectionString=...
DefaultContainerName=...

Add:

```
OnContextCreating="EntityDataSource_ContextCreating"
```

Leaving ContextTypeName empty.
And finally implement the following code in the corresponding .cs:

```
protected void EntityDataSource_ContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)  
{  
    <ContainerName> context = new <ContainerName>();  
    e.Context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;  
}
```

***ContainerName*** being your containername ofcourse.
If we would look at the original question then it would be MyWebsite2011Entities.